# Google OR-tools with here.com integration for Middle East region

Tags: google-maps, routes, here-api, or-tools, heremaps

I am looking at using Google OR for our route optimization tool targeted at the Middle East. I am planning to use here.com as the distance matrix input and want to understand if the OR tool will recognize the additional information received from here.com (such as open/closed roads, closed / temporarily prohibited points of passage) to build routes - can you please let us know? Thanks

Comment: or-tools doesn't know here.com and therefore won't do anything automatically for you. You will be in charge of chosing the solver and build a model on top of this chosen solver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said by Sascha, the routing library is completely agnostic of the source of the distance matrix. Getting the data must be done before calling the solver.

We do provide a code sample to access the Google Maps distance API. But nothing is integrated within the routing library itself.